# Invoking Web API Running in a Virtual Environment Parallels

Tags: asp.net

I am on a Mac. I am running Windows 7 using Parallels. In Windows 7 I created a ASP.NET Web API which can be accessed using the following URL:

```
http://localhost:1119/api/customers
```

How can I invoke this URL from my Mac HttpClient application?

- I tried replacing the localhost with IP address but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If you are using the development server, I don't think it allows remote connections. If you are using IIS or IIS Express, then you'll need to make sure to open up that port in your firewall if you are using one (which is what it sounds like).

You will definitely need to replace localhost with the virtual machines IP address / host name though.